Создание своей консольной команды для wep api asp .net c#
Всем привет. Мне нужно создать свою собственную консольную команду, например, для добавления пользователя-администратора. Я знаю, что такую штуку можно сделать на php, а вот как это сделать для web api на c#, не понимаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, это вообще возможно?

Что в вашем понимании "Консольная команда"? Ибо у меня что-то немного в голове не складывается то, что я понимаю под этим значением и PHP...

@EvgeniyZ # servermanager --add-user vasya

По идее вам нужно сделать отдельное консольное приложение для этого. Например операции управления юзерами вынести в отдельную библиотеку, которую будет использовать и сервер и консольная утилита. В решении можно создать несколько проектов.

Получается, если мне нужно будет развернуть весь сервер в докере, то под консольное приложение нужно будет выделить отдельный контейнер, а потом собрать в докер компоузе?
